# wp_list_pages children of current page with sequential numbering

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using this code to output (using wp_list_pages) a list of the current page children.

```
<?
if(wp_list_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&exclude=2')) {
wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&exclude=2');
}
elseif(get_the_title($post->post_parent) != the_title(' ' , ' ',false)) {
wp_list_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&title_li=&exclude=2');
} ?>
```

I would like to merge this code with another piece that enables me to add sequential numbering to the li elements, as shown here.

```
<?php $list_of_pages = wp_list_pages('echo=0&title_li=&depth=1' );
$list_pages = explode('<li class="',$list_of_pages); $len = count($list_pages);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $len-2; $i++) :
echo $list_pages[$i] . '<li  class="link-' . ($i+1) . ' ';
endfor; echo $list_pages[$i]; ?>
```

But i'm not particularly handy with PHP, if anyone could point me in the right direction to use the two snippets of code combined it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If im not mistaking the second snippet of code does in fact add sequential numbers to the list item class.

Comment: It does, but i don't know how to use the two pieces of code together in one.

Comment: code snippet 2 does what code snippet one does but adds sequential numbers to the list item class. You do not need to combine them since snippet two does what you would like it to do.

Comment: But the first code snippet lists the child pages of the current active page. Which the second code does not, nor can i seem to get it to.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit messy but it works and there is always room for refactoring the code below in the future. The code below first checks to see if a page is the parent of child page. If it is the child page it will only show the child. It adds an incremental counter to every list item(even the children) and the counter is initiated by calling echo=0. Hope this helps

```
<?php

    if(wp_list_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&exclude=2')) {
        $list_of_pages = wp_list_pages('echo=0&title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&exclude=2');
        $list_pages = explode('<li class="',$list_of_pages); $len = count($list_pages);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $len-2; $i++) :
        echo $list_pages[$i] . '<li class="link-'.($i+1). ' ';
        endfor; echo $list_pages[$i]; 
    }

    elseif(get_the_title($post->post_parent) != the_title(' ' , ' ',false)) {
    $list_of_pages = wp_list_pages('echo=0&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&title_li=&exclude=2');
    $list_pages = explode('<li class="',$list_of_pages); $len = count($list_pages);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $len-2; $i++) :
    echo $list_pages[$i] . '<li class="link-'.($i+1). ' ';
    endfor; echo $list_pages[$i];

} ?>
```